# Is it possible to add a searchbar to the "all sites" tab?

Tags: feature-request

Stackexchange has quite a few sites now  (about 100) and I am using a bunch of those. But lately it got really bothersome to go through the whole list to find the right one. And with the name changes, especially for gaming.stackexchange.com to Arqade it is even more frustrating.

What I propose is to add a filter or a search bar to the "all sites" tab, like this:

[image]

This search bar should filter the names of the sites and allow for further "keywords". Like "game" and "gaming" would also show the entry for Arqade or "writing" and "author" would show Writers etc.

Comment: [That circle does not look very free hand... ;)](http://i.imgur.com/TtR7x.png)

Comment: Look all sites at one eye-site at http://stackexchange.com/sites?view=grid

Comment: This functionality appears to have been implemented in the new top bar. (I asked a mod to tag this as [tag:status-completed], but the flag was declined; however, after re-reading the request, I still believe that it exactly matches the new top bar search feature.)

Comment: This is correct. The feature is implemented now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<s>BOOKMARKLET</s> USERSCRIPT ALERT!

[Super Multicollider Dropdown™ Search](https://stackapps.com/q/3513/10098)

It adds a search which works for all the tabs. Basically, it searches the first line of text, along with the `href` of the first link it encounters.

For the 'hot' tab, it searches by title and site URL.

**For the "sites" tab, it does exactly what you asked for--search by site name and/or url**

For the inbox, it searches by post/chatroom name and URL. Useful for finding all your chem.SE inbox items, or all your meta items, etc.

For the notification tab, it just searches notification text This is useful if you want to mask everything but your "badge" notifications(or "edit" notifications).

Comment: This is really nice. It would be even cooler if I could search for "gaming" and found Arqade. Perhaps some tags with display:none? But still this is a huge improvement.

Comment: @ayckoster: It does, I updated it to search the links as well. You may be using the older version. ANd there's a userscript coming up, so sit tight :)

Comment: @ayckoster: Updated to userscript

Answer (score 3):

Here is a slightly limited workaround presuming that you don't mind being limited to only the graduated sites or only the beta sites...

Here you see the footer of a Stack Exchange site (Meta in this case) -

[image]

Here is the ["Seasoned Advice"](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/) AKA cooking.se

[image]

All of the graduated sites are listed on all other graduated sites and vice versa for beta sites.
([thanks to ChrisF for the clarification](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/138117/is-it-possible-to-add-a-searchbar-to-the-all-sites-tab/138118#comment387894_138118))  -
 so you could just do a simple  <kbd>Ctrl+f</kbd> to search for the site you are looking for.  Press enter to toggle to the next occurance.

For completion here is a screen shot of a Stack Exchange beta site's footer

[image]

### Pro Tip

When you find the link and your browser has highlighted the word you can press the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key and then <kbd>Enter</kbd> to navigate to the highlighted link.

---

<sub>This is all in chrome but I'm sure the actions are similar through other browsers.</sub>

Comment: The big problem here is that the beta sites aren't listed in the graduated sites footer and vice versa.