# Quick search for "All sites" subwindow

Tags: feature-request, global-inbox

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to add a searchbar to the “all sites” tab?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/138117/is-it-possible-to-add-a-searchbar-to-the-all-sites-tab)

The "All sites" subwindow contains so many Stack Exchange websites that it becomes more and more cumbersome to find the site I am looking for.

I would like a "quick search" area with auto-completion and real-time filtering of the list displayed below:

[image: http://imgur.com/e6BZ3]

This question is a duplicate of

[Is it possible to add a searchbar to the "all sites" tab?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/138117/is-it-possible-to-add-a-searchbar-to-the-all-sites-tab)

and the following App (not tested yet) will probably be a good answer to it :

[Super Multicollider Dropdown™ Search](https://stackapps.com/questions/3513/super-multicollider-dropdown-search)

Comment: I like this. Maybe add to that a prioritization based on your own use of the various sites on the network... (i.e. your highest rep site is SO, then Programmers, so that answers will be weighted to show the SO responses first for a similar match)

Comment: Note that the script doesn't autocomplete, but it filters the site list down as you type. Effectively the same thing--better, in fact (because then you don't have to type more than three characters when you want to search for webapps, typing "web" gives you both webmasters and webapps).

Comment: @ManishEarthwantsmorewaffles: indeed. For a list with only around 83 elements with strongly diverging names, auto-complete would be a bit too much.